# Ngrx-Component / VSCode - Property binding ngrxLet not used by any directive on an embedded template

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-language-service

I am unable to use ngrx/component in any project as it continues giving me "Property binding ngrxLet not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".ng" error.

It does actually work, but for some reason the ide is not able to recognize it in any ways, I noticed as well that it is unable to recognize directives template guards (which from ivy should be available).

I just tried with a fresh ng new --minimal 10.0.5 app, with just the ngrx component module imported, and several other projects.

My guess is that my angular language service is not working correctly, I tried to reinstall it and nothing changed, this is the list of all my extensions.

- Yaml
- Typescript importer
- Angular language service
- SCSS Everywhere
- Prettier
- Move TS
- Material Icon Theme
- Jest Runner
- Eslint
- EditorConfig
- Bracket Pair Colorizer 2
- Better comments

Ivy is indeed enabled in those projects, I tried both with a fresh new 10.0 project and other projects with ivy enabled flag set to true

example stackblitz (which actually works, as I said, it even works in my local machine, it just gives an error on the ide because it cant recognize the directive): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gztygm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found that it was because I added the `import { ReactiveComponentModule } from '@ngrx/component';` only to my feature module. When I also added it to the root module, the error in the IDE went away.

Comment: I think your problem was different, as my qestion was made 5 months ago, when I'm quite the angular language service didn't support these kinds of directives (so it wasn't a bug, just wasn't supported yet)

They are doing many updates to the language service in the last patches if you check the changelog, so it may probably work right now (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Root module wasn't enough for me, it only worked when i imported it to the specific (lazy loaded?) module i was using it in